# How to handle Ropsten's smart contracts with Truffle?

Tags: truffle, testnets, ropsten

I work with Truffle, Metamask, and Windows PowerShell. I deployed my smart contract to Ropsten with Truffle by the below command in PowerShell:

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

Now, I need to interact with the deployed contract. Is it possible to handle Ropsten's smart contract with Truffle from PowerShell? if yes, Please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with truffle console :  `truffle console --network ropsten --verbose-rpc`.

You can then interact with the smart contract using the truffle API : https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts.

Answer (score 2):

As @clement mentioned, you can connect to Ropsten from Truffle console by command:

```
truffle console --network ropsten --verbose-rpc
```

After that, to communicate with your deployed contract, you should try the below command in Truffle console:

```
let instance = await contract_name.deployed()
```

Now, console knows the deployed contract as `instance` you defined by the last command. So, you can execute its functions just like this:

```
instance.function_name(<arg1, arg2, ...>)
```